# Does the centre of mass of an object undergoing thermal expansion move?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

I recently faced the question in an examination. The question is pretty straightforward.

Does the centre of mass of an object undergoing thermal expansion move?

---

P.S.

1. The solution for this question assumed that centre of mass would not move.

Comment: As it is formulated, the question is incomplete. The answer depends on the external conditions, the constraints imposed on the object. It may or not move. An example of moving is the COM of one of the components of a bi-metal plate which expands or contracts. Non-uniform friction may also results in motion. Only for a body completely isolated (zero external forces) the answer is true.

Comment: @nasu Lets say I am supplying heat by a gas at high temperature. I understand that the gas molecules collide with the walls of the solid which in turns raise its "Temperature". Further, I believe that my gas is doing a work by displacing atoms of the wall and thus applying a force on the wall. Does this force count as external force? Is this the "friction" you are talking about?

Comment: I was thinking about how the expanding object is supported.  If it sits on a table it rubs against the table as it expands.  Or one end may be  attached to a rigid attachment etc.  These various situations determines what the COM does.  Not how you heat it.

Comment: @nasu Okay I see your point clearly now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the question is missing an adjective, *uniform thermal expansion* would not change the center of mass. The way heat is transferred to the body might change the center of mass. Example : a block of butter if heated non uniformly, part of it melting and thus moving the CM due to change of shape.

Comment: That was the exact statement I needed.

Comment: If you have a bar with a fixed end,  uniform expansion (thermal or elastic) results in displacement of the COM,  doesn't it?

Comment: @nasu  yes,  the question is not well defined,  In fact the question should ask : a "body surrounded by  a heat bath" for the answer "would not move" to be correct.

Answer (score 2):

$\vec F_{ext} = M \vec a$ describes the motion of the center of mass (CM), where $\vec F_{ext}$ is the net external force, $M$ is the total mass, and $\vec a$ is the acceleraton of the CM.  With no net external force, the acceleration of the CM is constant; but if the CM has an initial velocity $\vec v$, it is moving and continues moving with constant $\vec v$ with no $\vec F_{ext}$.  The correct answer is the CM will not change velocity; if the velocity is intially zero it will remain zero, but if the initial velocity is not zero it will remain constant and the CM moves with this constant velocity.

Comment: Lets say I am supplying heat by a gas at high temperature. I understand that the gas molecules collide with the walls of the solid which in turns raise its "Temperature". Further, I believe that my gas is doing a work by displacing atoms of the wall and thus applying a force on the wall. Does this force count as external force?

Comment: Considering the gas and the enclosing walls as the system, this is an internal force. It does not affect the CM.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I have taken my system as a solid object and I am heating it over a Bunsen burner. Hence I believe that the gas in the flame must be applying a force on the solid object as its molecules collide with those of the solid. Is this the sort of external force everyone is referring to?

Comment: @Tony Stark  Sorry, I did misunderstand.  Yes the pressure from the gas in the flame on the solid does provide a force on the solid; it contributes to the net external force on the solid (in addition to gravity and the constraint that holds the solid).  The motion of the CM is due to the net external force as nasu discussed in the earlier comment.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the composition of the object. If it is made up non-uniformly,of materials with different coefficients of expansion, the center of gravity would move, even if the heat were uniformly distributed.